# Remove jQuery dependency

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a small HTML page, which holds an image with zoom-in capabilities.

```
<div id="zoom-container">
    <div id="img_wrapper" class="img-wrapper">
        <img id="img_place" src="Figures/Species_copy_number.png" onclick="cenas()" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I use jQuery only in the following code:

```
window.zoomedIn = false;
function cenas() {
    var el = this, elp = $("#zoom-container");
    var zoomContainer = $("#img_wrapper");

    if (window.zoomedIn) {
        zoomContainer.css("transform", "");
        elp.css("overflow", "auto");
        window.zoomedIn = false;
    } else {
        var top = el.offsetTop;
        var left = el.offsetLeft - 0.25*zoomContainer[0].clientWidth;
        var tro = (Math.abs(elp.offsetTop - el.offsetTop) > 0) ? "bottom" : "top";
        tro += (Math.abs(elp.offsetLeft - el.offsetLeft) > 0) ? " right" : " left";
        zoomContainer.css({"transform-origin": tro, "transform": "scale(2)"});
        window.zoomedIn = true;
    }
}
```

It seems useless to import a huge file for one js function. I tried to remove it and make everything working using native js. So far I have this:

```
window.zoomedIn = false;
function cenas() {
    var el = this, elp = document.getElementById("zoom-container");
    var zoomContainer = document.getElementById("img_wrapper");

    if (window.zoomedIn) {
        elp.setAttribute("overflow", "auto");
        window.zoomedIn = false;
    } else {
        var top = el.offsetTop;
        var left = el.offsetLeft - 0.25*zoomContainer.clientWidth;
        var tro = (Math.abs(elp.offsetTop - el.offsetTop) > 0) ? "bottom" : "top";
        tro += (Math.abs(elp.offsetLeft - el.offsetLeft) > 0) ? " right" : " left";
        zoomContainer.setAttribute("transform-origin", tro + " 0px; transform: scale(2);");
        window.zoomedIn = true;
    }
}
```

Which seems to perform the correct css tranformations, but nothing happens.

Can someone help me remove the jquery dependency?

Thanks

**EDIT:** working as:

```
    window.zoomedIn = false;
    function cenas() {
        var el = this, elp = document.getElementById("zoom-container");
        var zoomContainer = document.getElementById("img_wrapper");

        if (window.zoomedIn) {
            elp.setAttribute("style", "overflow: auto");
            zoomContainer.setAttribute("style", "transform :\"\"");
            window.zoomedIn = false;
        } else {
            var top = el.offsetTop;
            var left = el.offsetLeft - 0.25*zoomContainer.clientWidth;
            var tro = (Math.abs(elp.offsetTop - el.offsetTop) > 0) ? "bottom" : "top";
            tro += (Math.abs(elp.offsetLeft - el.offsetLeft) > 0) ? " right" : " left";
            zoomContainer.setAttribute("style", "transform-origin: "+ tro + " 0px; transform: scale(2);");
            window.zoomedIn = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `elp.setAttribute("overflow", "auto");` should be `elp.setAttribute("style", "overflow: auto");`.  You need to fix the other `setAttribute` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"transform-origin"` is not an attribute.  `"style"` is the attribute you want to set.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of setAttribute you can use style.property = value**